# Deriving the expectation $E\left[\left | \sum_{i=1}^N X_{i} e^{j \varphi_i} \right |\right]$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, expected-value, absolute-value

When $\varphi_i$ are i.i.d. RVs that are uniformly distributed between $\left(-\frac{\pi}{a}, \frac{\pi}{a}\right)$ and $X_{i}$ are also some i.i.d RV, does the following holds? If yes, how can it be proved?
$$E\left[\left | \sum_{i=1}^N X_{i} e^{j \varphi_i} \right |\right] =  N \cdot E\left[X_{i}\right] \cdot E\left[\cos(\varphi_i)\right] $$

Comment: It is false for $N=1$, because $\mathbb{E}[|Xe^{j\varphi}|]=\mathbb{E}[|X|]=\mathbb{E}[X]$ if $X\geqslant 0$ a.s and $$\mathbb{E}[\cos(\varphi)]=\frac{a}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi/a}^{\pi/a} \cos(\vartheta)d\vartheta={\rm sinc}\left(\frac{\pi}{a}\right)\neq 0$$ in general.

Comment: @Tuvasbien that´s quite a simple and good example. But do you think it could be expressed in terms of the expectations of  and cos()?

Comment: I don't think you can, to know $\sqrt{X}$, you have to know the law of $X$, knowing $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is not sufficient. But you can compute $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^N X_ie^{j\varphi_i}\right|^2\right]$$ because we have no square root anymore. Indeed, $$ \mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^N X_ie^{j\varphi_i}\right|^2\right]=\sum_{k,\ell=1}^N \mathbb{E}[X_k]\mathbb{E}[X_{\ell}]\mathbb{E}\left[e^{j(\varphi_k-\varphi_{\ell})}\right]=\frac{N^2a^2}{2\pi^2}\mathbb{E}[X]^2\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{a}\right)\right) $$

Comment: @Tuvasbien I have derived the second order of the absolute value (but the form is different from yours, anyway I guess they are equivalent). Then do you think it’s straightforward to derive the fourth, sixth, and eighth moments of the absolute value? I try to use my approach, but it is so tedious.